# How can I make a bash string of command with redirect and pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection

I want to make a bash string of commands with redirect and/or pipe, and use it to either display the string of commands or execute the string of commands. A simple command without redirect or pipe works, but a string of commands with redirect or pipe does not. For example,

```
command="echo 1"
$command
echo "$command"
```

would display

```
1
echo 1
```

However,

```
command="echo 1 | cat"
$command
echo "$command"
```

would display

```
1 | cat
echo 1 | cat
```

but, I want

```
1
echo 1 | cat
```

Similarly for redirect,

```
command="echo 1 | cat > 1.out"
$command
echo "$command"
```

would display

```
1 | cat > 1.out
echo 1 | cat > 1.out
```

but I want

```
echo 1 | cat > 1.out
```

with a new file named "1.out" with content 1 in it.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `cat` is a command that receives file-name/s as parameter/s and you're trying to pipe `echo 1` into it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want the shell to evaluate the string as a command, tell it to do so with `eval`:

```
eval "$command"
```